# Cannot change mvc layout in SiteCore 8.0 (update 3) from code

Tags: c#, web-config, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to change layout in SiteCore 8.0 (update 3) for all my pages from code behind.
I am using layout resolver pipeline for it.
i can debug & see changed path, but cannot get updated layout on UI. I have seen various post by googling, who are doing same thing but those are quite old (older then 2-3 yrs).

below is my layout resolver pipeline code

```
  public class LayoutResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public LayoutResolver()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("PipeLine: ctor() has been called");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the layout for the page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
     public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("PipeLine: This is atleast called");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        if (!CanProcess())
        {
            return;
        }
        Context.Page.FilePath = "/Views/Shared/BusinessLayout_Two.cshtml";
    }

    private static bool CanProcess()
    {
        return Context.Database != null
                && !IsCore(Context.Database);
    }
    private static bool IsCore(Database database)
    {
        return database.Name == Constants.CoreDatabaseName;
    }
}
```

EDIT : showconfig.config show my resolver register in config.
SiteCoreSample.Helpers.LayoutResolver is my resolver.

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LayoutResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="SiteCoreSample.Helpers.LayoutResolver, SiteCoreSample" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferMvcLayout, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferControllerRequest, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.HttpRequest.CheckDevice, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.PageEditorHandleNoLayout, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.config"/>
```

[image: Debug screen shot]

Comment: And what is the problem? Exception? Nothing? Anything in the logs? Can you add a Log.Info in your code and check if it's there? Have you added your new processor to the Sitecore configuration? Can you see it when you open `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak : Nothing happens, i can see variable set with my value in debug view but not reflected my layout in front view

no exception nothing happen, execution happened as per code but not reflected in UI.

configuration updated & shown in showconfig.aspx as i updated in EDITED.

Comment: Can you try to add it directly after `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LayoutResolver` and before `TransferMvcLayout` processor?

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak , i have updated as per instruct. but no joy

Comment: @MarekMusielak my intention is to change layout at run time if you can suggest any other way it will be useful. I am newbie for sitecore.

Comment: Never tried it on my own. You can try to remove the original `LayoutResolver` and use only yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using MVC you need to add procesors to a different set of pipelines, the `LayoutResolver` pipeline you mention is only relevant for Webforms projects..

I would suggest you create another `Layout` item under `/sitecore/layout/Layouts` for your secondary MVC layout. Then create processor that will switch the layout item to the secondary one as required:

```cs
using System;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageRendering;

namespace MyProject.CMS.Custom.Pipelines.GetPageRendering 
{
    public class GetCustomLayoutRendering : GetPageRenderingProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(GetPageRenderingArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Result == null)
                return;

            if (!ShouldSwitchLayout()) //or whatever your custom logic is
                return;

            args.Result.LayoutId = new Guid("{guid-to-alt-layout}");
            args.Result.Renderer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the patch the processor in to the `mvc.getPageRendering` pipeline:

```xml
<mvc.getPageRendering>
  <processor type="MyProject.CMS.Custom.Pipelines.GetPageRendering.GetCustomLayoutRendering, MyProject.CMS.Custom"/>
</mvc.getPageRendering>
```

It's important to set `args.Result.Renderer` to null, since that will force the rendering to be refetched and use the alternative layout from the ID you just set.

Comment: Let me try, will get back to you shortly

Comment: awesome! It works, I was onto it since 3 days, you made my day! +1.+2, .. +n :)